# regEx to validate File name "GktAb_140715T1015.txt"

Tags: java

I am writing a regularExpression to validate FileName some thing like this "GktAb_140715T1015.txt".

PLease provide regEx to validate File name

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: This is not a free coding service :(

Comment: Something like `^GktAb_140715T1015\.txt$`

Comment: What kind of patterns are you expecting? Please be more specific.

Comment: If you do not know regex but need help try at least to explain what are the validation criteria.

Comment: What is the sample input and output?. What is considered as *correct* match?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this expression  **^GktAb_+[0-9A-Z]+.txt$**